# Spark load csv files and memorise filename in column

Tags: python, apache-spark-sql

We have a blob storage where plenty of files are arriving during the whole day.
I have a Databricks notebook running in batch read the directorylist, looping the files and send them all into a Azure SQLDW.Works fine.
After that the processed files are moved into a archive.
But the process of looping the filelist, appending each one of them and adding the filename to a column goes a bit slow.
I was wondering if this could be done in 1 run. The loading off all csv's at once can be done, but how to memorise the corresponding filenames in a column.

Anybody has a suggestion ?

Comment: where you want to keep the file name ? The dataframe where you are loading csv?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are couple of ways which I can think of

```
1. spark.read.format("csv").load("path").select(input_file_name())

2. spark.sparkContext.wholeTextFiles("path").map{case(x,y) => x} <-- avoid if data is huge
```

Both provides all filenames in the given path.Where as former one is based on DF might be faster than later RDD one.

Note : Have n't tested the solution.

Comment: This did the jobsqlOUT = spark.read.schema(sqlSchema).option("delimiter",";").csv(csvPaths[:csvCount]).withColumn("Blob_FileName",input_file_name())